# reloadData() fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, xcode6, reloaddata

The app crashes at the line 
[image]

> ```
> class ImageValueCell: UITableViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
>
> @IBOutlet weak var imagesList: UITableView!
>   var imageArray: NSArray!
>
> override func awakeFromNib() {
>     //super.awakeFromNib()
>     // Initialization code
>     imagesList.delegate = self;
>     imagesList.dataSource = self;
>     imageArray = NSArray()
>     imagesList.reloadData()
> }
>
> func addImagesValue(objectList: NSMutableArray, machine: WIFIMachine){
>     imageArray = objectList
>     imagesList.reloadData() //CRASHED HERE
>   }
> ```
>
> }

I trace through and found that imageList is nil when the crash happens. This is a custom cell with a UITableView created on the storyboard. Can anyone advise me on the possible solution that i could try?

Comment: check if your imagesList is not nil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are calling `addImagesValue` before the `awakeFromNib` is called, then your code will empty the array. I don't think that is what you want. Here is a better solution:

```
class ImageValueCell: UITableViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var imagesList: UITableView!
    var imageArray: NSArray = NSArray() {
        didSet {
            // whenever the imageArray changes, reload the imagesList
            if let imagesList = imagesList {
                imagesList.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        // why isn't the below done from inside the nib file? That's how I would do it.
        imagesList.delegate = self
        imagesList.dataSource = self
        imagesList.reloadData()
    }

    func addImagesValue(objectList: NSMutableArray, machine: WIFIMachine){
        imageArray = objectList
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, i manage to get rid of the error. However `  imagesList.reloadData()` is never called when the size of imageArray increase from 0-1. Table was not reloaded.

Comment: Base on your original question, that sounds reasonable and expected. If you change the `imageArray` while `imagesList` is `nil`, the `reloadData()` method shouldn't be called. That said, I made a minor change to my answer.